# Deployment Failure (Slack → Azure)

Tags: azure, slack, slack-api, msdeploy, azure-deployment

We're trying to integrate Jumpcloud with Slack using Azure but we're facing an error:

{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"Failed","message":"Failed to download package.\r\nARM-MSDeploy Deploy Failed: 'System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.\r\n at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)\r\n at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)\r\n --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)\r\n at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(TimeSpan timeout)\r\n at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.<Download>d_17.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.<Download>d15.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.<DownloadPackageAndSettings>d27.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.<DownloadAndDeployPackage>d_25.MoveNext()\r\n---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.\r\n at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)\r\n at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)<---\r\n'"}]}

It's a permission issue apparently? We tried accessing the URL provided in the ARM Template and it also brings the Forbidden Access issue.

Can we get an assistance in this matter or help to identify this issue?

I'm following this documentation: https://github.com/TheJumpCloud/jumpcloud-slack-app/tree/master/Azure

Comment: Could you please refer this BLOG: https://rakodako.com/how-to-integrate-slack-with-azure-devops/ ,It may helps

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.